# Searching for standalone unix development board to connect DC motors

Tags: usb, c, driver, board

I though a bit about the board and came to the conclusion that it may be more intelligent to use a stand-alone component which provides serial ports and an unix os which I then can control over the network. I want to write the port driver myself so it shouldn't require to implement a big sub protocol like I have to do with USB and similar.

Which board is recommended for such a task?

I found so far:

- gooseberry
- beagleBoneBlack (does this require a host?)
- cuubieboard
- else?

*they mostly support the arm branch of FreeBSD as fallback archlinuxarm is there too*

Is there a better port then the old serial one?

Comment: @CamilStaps Why do you hate to say this? Do you think their docs are good enough to write an own driver (I hate java) but they seem to have a readable c layer underneath

Comment: Which Unix flavor? And are talking host or device-side Unix?

Comment: @jippie I prefer a BSD but I would also accept GNU/Linux (which may be better from device support). Device-side should be unix. Host-side will be too but if I use a network connection it doesn't matter that much.

Comment: In that case just use an arduino with a network shield, no need to overcomplicate things.

Comment: It seems strange that the board must use a huge OS like Unix, but USB is too big to bother with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can take pretty much any AVR development board and load [VUSB](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) on it. It's a fully open source USB stack for the AVR. I've used it in a number of projects along with LIBUSB. It works great and runs on pretty much anything. Note though that since it's software based it's only USB1, shouldn't be a problem in your case though.

Comment: You could also use any of the AVR devices that have built-in USB PHYs, to make your life easier. Or you could buy a Arduino Leonardo, and dump the bootloader.

Comment: I have updated the question. I think I want to move from usb to a standalone device which provides a serial port to make things easier. Else I am to dependent on the board itself whereas I am more interested in the driver development